# Which design pattern applies if I go one time instead of ten times to hit a database?

Tags: design-patterns, oop

I am looking at a piece of code which wraps all disparate query data in a single object. Is there a design pattern that applies to this scenario?

Comment: The "cause future maintainers a headache" pattern? Seriously, combining disparate data in an object doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: Maybe the Aggregate pattern? http://goodcoffeegoodcode.blogspot.com/2010/04/enhancing-aggregate-pattern-in-domain.html

Comment: What makes you think there's a pattern for this, that programming is a pattern at all, and that a pattern (if it exists) is most appropriate for you? Ask about your actual coding problem, describe the [goal and not the step](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html), and try again. We'll try to find solutions to your problem, we won't try to force a solution into a box.

Comment: @GMan isn't there pattern for anything? :)

Answer (score 0):

That really doesn't qualify as a pattern.

Even disparate data must have something in common and having that in a single database call could be considered good programming.

Of course, if it's possible the data later needs to be distributed or done in parallel calls (typically stored procedures are sequential, so having a client trigger several in parallel and wait for all to complete can often be quicker), such an architecture might be considered a premature optimization.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really sure what you are getting at... but I would call this a FACTORY - then the implementation of the factory could make optimization choices about how to poulate its members. (presumably by fewer database calls or whatever other trick you can come up with)

Comment: i dont think factory is even close to it. remeber factories are fundamentally creational patterns

Comment: yes - OP seems to be creating some object that is comprised of possibly several database call result sets...